# reference request for verse: Satvam tatvam para tvam cha tvat tryam hanakina tritatva rupini Radha sa api Radhika

Tags: scripture, upanishads, reference-request, shloka, radha

Trying to find the reference for this verse:

> Satvam tatvam para tvam cha tvat tryam hanakina tritatva rupini Radha sa api Radhika

सत्वं तत्वं पर त्वं च त्वत त्र्यम हनकिना त्रितत्व रूपिणी राधा सापि राधिका

```
सत्त्वम् (satvam): Existence, reality
तत्त्वम् (tattvam): Truth, essence
पर (para): Supreme
त्वम् (tvam): You
च (cha): And
त्वत् (tvat): Yours
त्रयम् (trayam): Three
हनकिना (hanakina): by Your lover
त्रितत्व (tritatva): Triad, the state of being threefold
रूपिनि (rupini): Having the form
राधा (Radha): Radha
सा अपि (sa api): She also
राधिका (Radhika): Radhika
```

wanted to know if its from **Gautamiya Tantra**  any suggestions are appreciated.